# "The boys who wore " vs "The boys wearing"

Tags: relative-clauses, gerund-clauses

Which sentence structure is correct?

> *The boys **who wore** red shirts were Manchester Utd. fans.*

or

> *The boys **wearing** red shirts were Manchester Utd. fans*

Answer (score 1):

> (1) The boys who wore red shirts were Manchester U fans.
>
> (2) The boys wearing red shirts were Manchester U fans

Both are fine. The difference is a grammatical one: In (1) "boys" is modified by the relative clause "who wore red shirts", whereas in (2) it is modified by the gerund-participial clause "wearing red shirts". There's no real difference in meaning, though (2) being more succinct has the edge.